# how to change the design of the documentation popup in VS CODE?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

Is it possible to cutomize the theme of this documentation ?  main concern is that I wish to :

- format the signature of the function, like going to a new line for each parameter.
- change the color of the signature parameters, like putting the function name in blue.

Comment: try a different theme or customize the theme colors, also look at the syntax highlight colors

Comment: Do you know what are the theme color properties of the documentation popup ?